# get results of other page on my own page

Tags: php, jquery, html

As example this page [here](http://www1.dasoertliche.de/?form_name=search_nat_ext&cmd=cmd_show&kw=&pc=&ci=&buc=&kgs=&buab=&zbuab=&context=0&action=44&page=1&sb_form=search_nat_ext). You can see a forumlar. Now I create on my page a formular like this:

[image]

And if I enter something (name of a person, phone number, ...), I want get the result of the other page, on my page? Can I do this without database access from the other page?

Comment: What do you mean you want to get the results of the other page onto your page? Like using an `Iframe`?

Comment: Are you referring to a form? `<form method="post" aciton="otherpage.php">`

Comment: according to the example behind that 'here' hyperlink he wants to do some kind of google search

Comment: I want to get the result of the other page on my page. If i search a person with the name "foo bar", I want to get the result of the other page on my page (maybe in a div container). No I dont want to do a google search. I want to get the result of the other page on my page.

Comment: What other page? Have you looked into ajax?

Comment: the other page is the example page [page](http://www1.dasoertliche.de/?form_name=search_nat_ext&cmd=cmd_show&kw=&pc=&ci=&buc=&kgs=&buab=&zbuab=&context=0&action=44&page=1&sb_form=search_nat_ext), and I dont have access to the database on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoringly to ["the other page"](http://www1.dasoertliche.de/?form_name=search_nat_ext&cmd=cmd_show&kw=&pc=&ci=&buc=&kgs=&buab=&zbuab=&context=0&action=44&page=1&sb_form=search_nat_ext) its not possible. If there is no API provided for that service you can only display an iframe or redirect to the search results with given search parameters.